# Show that the following polynomial is irreducible over $GF(2^2)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

**Question:** $GF(2^2)$ consists of four elements $0,1,\omega,\omega +1$, where $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$. Verify that $f(y)=\omega+\omega y+\omega y^2+y^3$ is an irreducible polynomial over $GF(2^2)$.

My background is weak on this and I cannot find any material that outlines a procedure for $GF(p^n)$. I'm looking for a procedure that I can do by hand.

**Attempt:** If $f(y)$ is reducible then we can write $f(y)=g(y)h(y)$, where $\deg(g(y)) < 3$ and $\deg(h(y)) < 3$. In fact, we need $\deg(f(y))=\deg(g(y))+\deg(h(y))$; i.e. one of $g(y)$ or $h(y)$ must be degree 1. Hence, a degree 1 polynomial must divide $f(y)$ for it to be reducible.

My plan was to brute force check that every single degree 1 polynomial of $GF(2^2)$ does not divide $f(y)$, and hence $f(y)$ is not reducible. But I feel uneasy about the elements of $GF(2^2)$ and the "rules" that I need to play by. In other words, what are all of the degree 1 polynomials of $GF(2^2)$? Also, is my procedure valid?

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your approach will work. Simply verify that $f(y)$ is not zero for $y=0,1,\omega,\omega+1$.  All you really need to do is work with $\omega$ as a variable, but  whenever you see a $\omega^2$, replace it with with $\omega+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps so far are valid. Now, because the polynomial lies in a finite field, instead of checking 16 linear polynomials you only need to check that $f(x)\ne0$ for each of the four elements $x\in\mathbb F_4$.
$$f(0)=\omega$$
$$f(1)=1+\omega$$
$$f(\omega)=1$$
$$f(1+\omega)=1$$
Therefore $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_4$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Quick follow up question: On the source I'm referencing the person is showing that $x^4 + x + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. Instead of just plugging in 0 and 1, he delves into the method that I outlined above. Would plugging in 0 and 1 work in that situation?

Comment: Plugging in $0$ and $1$ would *not* work, because that only shows that your polynomial has no roots, i.e. no linear factors. But maybe it was the product of two quadratics. (As it happens, it’s not, because there’s only one quadratic irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$, namely $x^2+x+1$.)

Comment: @Lubin Oh. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

As a set $GF(4)$ consists of four elements: 0,1,$\omega, 1+\omega$. So you just need to plug each one into $f$ and see that it does not vanish.